# Webscrape stock data

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape the sector weights and holdings from yahoo finance for a given etf/mutual fund. I am having trouble identifying what to *find* when using `BeautifulSoup`. For example:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request
ticker='SPY'
address=('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/'+ticker+
             '/holdings?p='+ticker)
source = urllib.request.urlopen(address).read()      
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
sector_weights = soup.find()
```

I can read the address fine and when I inspect the website, the section I want highlighted is:

```
<div class="MB(25px) " data-reactid="18">
```

But when I try `soup.find_all('div', class_='MB(25px) ')` it returns an empty list.

I would like to do the same thing for holdings, but the same issue came about.

P.S. if anybody know of any good website to scrape region information, that would be much appreciated, morningstar does not work sadly.

Comment: This is not a working example but I think you should remove the space in the name of the class: class_='MB(25px) ' should be class_='MB(25px)'

Comment: That is the name if you inspect it, it has the space, which I know it is strange. Which part is not working for you as an example? I thought I gave everything in order to test it for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'MB(25px) ' should 'Mb(25px)'
The name is case-sensitive ***and*** you need to remove the trailing space in the literal. Your code works when I make those two changes.

I also had to remove your parser reference and let BeautifulSoup use the default parser, html.parser, because the code crashed when I used your parser reference.